# print pointer address of reference class

Tags: c++, c, pointers, java-native-interface

Code Summary:

Need to pass object of Camera From TestCamera.cpp to Test1.cpp.
I created a object of class into TestCamera.cpp
Now, I want to pass this to Test1, so I passed this to another object.

Anyhow I am getting error of "Camera*" into Test1.cpp .

I am new to CPP. Is it perfect way to pass another class & print it's pointer value?

**TestCamera.cpp**

```
Camera * cameraClient=static_cast<Camera *>();

    (Test1 *)->captureImage(*cameraClient*);
```

**Test1.cpp**

```
int Test1::captureImage(const Camera*  Cam) {

    jint lResult;
    jlong ad = (jlong)&Cam;
        LOGI("Test1: pointer : APP: %ld",ad);
```

Comment: You should show a bit more code, because those two lines you showed in `TestCamera.cpp` are so wild I can't even begin to figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not getting your whole code, but just giving you hint that you are passing it wrong way..

you need to pass like this:

> (Test1 *)->captureImage(cameraClient);

but, i doubt because you are not allocating memory to cameraClient.

below is extra advise, which is out of your question:

in C++, when you want to create an object of a class dynamically, then you need to allocate memory using **new** like below:

```
Camera * cameraClient= new Camera;
```

which instantiate class of Camera & then pass it to CaptureImage if Test1 class already instantiated..

Comment: for both I need to include Camera.h class. I am getting :previous definition of 'class: error.

Comment: your question is just to print pointer value, i had given adequate answer to your question. if any other error, then post full code with another question

Comment: Should I write : int Test1::captureImage(const Camera*  camera). 
Camera * in Test1 class or I need to use Camera only ?

Comment: if you are passing pointer then you need like i wrote in my answer, then you need to keep Test1::captureImage(Camera* camera).

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet in TestCamera.cpp is not right, when you say that you are creating an object then you need to either use `new` operator or define an object as below

```
Camera * cameraClientPtr=new Camera; // For default constructor
Camera cameraClientObj;
```

The way you invoke method `captureImage` also not right. If you have `Test1` pointer created using any of the aforementioned way then you invoke the method as below,

```
Test1Ptr->captureImage(cameraClientPtr);

Test1Obj.captureImage(&cameraClientObj);
```

Comment: Should I write : int Test1::captureImage(const Camera*  camera). 
Camera * in Test1 class or I need to use Camera only ?

Comment: If you are passing as a pointer then use `int Test1::captureImage(const Camera* camera)`, for passing as a reference `int Test1::captureImage(const Camera& camera)`. You can go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) and this [link](http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html) for more information on how to pass data to method.